# Jquery toggle won't work for lists item inside a list item

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a list which is inside a list item:

```
       <ul id="selected-list" class="droptrue sort-drop">
            <li class="sortedli" style="">Call list
                <ul id="select-navlist" style="float: right;">
                    <li class="sel-display">xx</li>
                    <li><a href="#">aa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">bb</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">cc</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">dd</a></li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
          </ul>
```

I'm using jQuery to toggle the color of the list item with class name "del-display" so it changes it's colour to orange. However, the item it self doesn't display when I save and run my toggle code:

```
$(".sel-display").toggle(function () {
            $(this).css("background", "#ffcc00");
            //$(this).css("background-position", "140px 5px");
    });​
```

I've made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/noscirre/3fwZn/

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: That use of toggle has been deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: are you toggling on hover? click? what triggers the toggle?

Comment: Looks like that jsFiddle is including MooTools instead of jQuery :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it something like this:

```
$('.sel-display').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("highlighted")){
        $(this).removeClass("highlighted");
        $(this).css({"background", "#ffffff"});
    }else{
        $(this).addClass("highlighted");
        $(this).css({"background", "#ffcc00"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a find on all list items with a certain class name something like the following:

```
$('.sel-display').find('li').hasClass('del-display');
```

Im not sure if thats code correct because im writing it free hand but i think you might need something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not the greatest solution, but it's something?

http://jsfiddle.net/3fwZn/7/

**Javascript:**

```
$(".sel-display").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('del');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.del {
    background-color: #ffcc00 !important;
}
```